# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addAnnotatedClass

Tags: hibernate, jpa, annotations, hibernate-annotations, persistence.xml

I am new to JPA & hibernate, when I try this [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaPersistenceAPI/article.html)  .
I added the following provider in my persistence.xml,

```
<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
```

and I am getting this error..

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.jboss.logging).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/hibernate/cfg/Configuration;
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Ejb3Configuration.java:1421)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.addNamedAnnotatedClasses(Ejb3Configuration.java:1391)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.addClassesToSessionFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:1184)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:1048)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:291)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:373)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:56)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:48)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:32)
    at de.vogella.jpa.simple.main.Main.main(Main.java:17)
```

Kindly help to resolve this error .
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It look like the Hibernate Annotation jar is wrong. It is not compatible with the jar version. So that is why it showing the `"java.lang.NoSuchMethodError"`

Could you please tell me the which jar version are you currently working , please specify the version ?
Then only we have to easily address this.

Which Hibernate version are you currently working ?

Which Annotation version are you currently working ?

please specify the version.
 Thanks.

Comment: <dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
  <version>4.2.0.CR1</version>
</dependency>
  
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
 <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
 <version>3.2.0.Final</version>
</dependency>

Comment: thanks for your reply.. here is some dependency i have used, <dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
  <version>4.2.0.CR1</version>
</dependency>
  
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
 <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
 <version>3.2.0.Final</version>
</dependency>

Comment: wait i will check and let you know that.

Comment: hibernate - 3.2.6.ga
hibernate-annotations - 3.2.1.ga
hibernate-commons-annotations - 3.0.0.ga
hibernate-entitymanager - 3.2.1.ga

Comment: update your annotataion jar and let me know that what happens.

Comment: Thanks for solution, now it giving error.... Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Hibernate Dialect must be explicitly set
 at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:720)
 at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:121)
 at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:83)
 at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:60)
 at de.vogella.jpa.simple.main.Main.main(Main.java:17

Comment: sir, kindly also help to resolve this...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14976165/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-could-not-initialize-class-net-sf-cglib-proxy-en/14976259#14976259

Comment: @bhushan, you something missed on the class path. so that is why it shows the "MappableContainerException". Some classes are not loaded related to the DB Manager.

Answer (score 5):

Check your version of Hibernate, you need hibernate-core 3.6.0 or higher to use the method `addAnnotatedClass` of `org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration`

Answer (score 1):

In addition:

I've faced the same problem and I came to this page after googling for an answer and none of these answers helped me, so in case that somebody passes through the same problem:

I had an `ArrayList<Entity>` and when I wanted to add an item to the arraylist, the NoSuchMethodException encountered. The problem was that the `ArrayList` had to be an `Array`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following dependencies...

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.4.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.5-Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.4.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.7</version>
</dependency>
```