# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer

Tags: web-services, hibernate, rest, jpa, cglib

when i am trying to request to Rest service at time of response it getting exception..

```
Feb 21, 2013 2:34:49 PM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse mapMappableContainerException
SEVERE: The exception contained within MappableContainerException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.cglib.CGLIBLazyInitializer.getProxyFactory(CGLIBLazyInitializer.java:117)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.cglib.CGLIBProxyFactory.postInstantiate(CGLIBProxyFactory.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.buildProxyFactory(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:162)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.<init>(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.<init>(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityEntityModeToTuplizerMapping.<init>(EntityEntityModeToTuplizerMapping.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.<init>(EntityMetamodel.java:302)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init>(AbstractEntityPersister.java:434)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.persister.PersisterFactory.createClassPersister(PersisterFactory.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:226)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1300)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:713)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:121)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:52)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:34)
    at de.vogella.jpa.simple.main.Main.getObj(Main.java:18)
    at com.poshs.webapp.MyResource.setIt(MyResource.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
```

this result i get after run mvn dependency:tree

```
[INFO] +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:jar:1.8:compile 
[INFO] |  +- asm:asm:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-json:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- stax:stax-api:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.2.3-1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- javax.xml.stream:stax-api:jar:1.0-2:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-jaxrs:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-xc:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.8.2:test
[INFO] +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-client:jar:1.8:test
[INFO] +- org.glassfish.distributions:web-all:jar:10.0-build-20080430:test
[INFO] +- org.glassfish.embedded:gf-embedded-api:jar:1.0-alpha-4:test
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.api:dtds:jar:resources:9.0.2:test
[INFO] |  \- org.glassfish.api:schemas:jar:resources:9.0.2:test
[INFO] +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.0-alpha4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.0-beta1:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.openejb:commons-dbcp-all:jar:1.3-r699049:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.pool:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.nuiton.thirdparty:asm-attrs:jar:1.5.4-snapshot:compile
[INFO] +- org.sonatype.sisu.inject:cglib:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.jvnet.hudson.dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1-hudson-3:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:ejb3-persistence:pom:3.3.2.Beta1:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate:jar:3.2.6.ga:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.0.1B:compile
[INFO] |  +- asm:asm-attrs:jar:1.5.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  \- cglib:cglib:jar:2.1_3:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-annotations:jar:3.2.1.ga:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.persistence:persistence-api:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:3.0.0.ga:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:3.2.1.ga:compile
[INFO] |  +- jboss:javassist:jar:3.3.ga:compile
[INFO] |  \- jboss:jboss-archive-browsing:jar:5.0.0alpha-200607201-119:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator-annotation-processor:jar:5.0.0.Beta1:compile
[INFO] +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils-bean-collections:jar:1.8.3:compile
[INFO] +- jboss:jboss-common:jar:4.2.2.GA:compile
[INFO] +- javassist:javassist:jar:3.12.1.GA:compile
[INFO] +- hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:pom:3.4.0.GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:ejb3-persistence:jar:1.0.2.GA:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:3.3.0.SP1:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.0.0.Beta1:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Beta3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.1.GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:0.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- de.odysseus.juel:juel-spi:jar:2.2.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- de.odysseus.juel:juel-api:jar:2.2.5:compile
[INFO] |  \- de.odysseus.juel:juel-impl:jar:2.2.5:compile
[INFO] +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:jar:1.7.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.sitebricks:slf4j:jar:0.8.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.google.inject:guice:jar:2.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
[INFO] +- postgresql:postgresql:jar:9.1-901.jdbc4:compile
[INFO] +- com.tunnelvisionlabs:antlr4:jar:4.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.tunnelvisionlabs:antlr4-runtime:jar:4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.abego.treelayout:org.abego.treelayout.core:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.antlr:antlr-runtime:jar:3.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.antlr:stringtemplate:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.antlr:ST4:jar:4.0.7:compile
[INFO] +- cglib:cglib-nodep:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:4.1:compile
[INFO] \- org.ow2.asm:asm-util:jar:4.1:compile
[INFO]    \- org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:jar:4.1:compile
```

This is get after run the mvn dependency:tree ,
i have checked my dependency for cglib but i not sure for version compatible, kindly check let me know which are compatible for my project.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You probably miss a jar, for cglib.

When does this happen (unitTest, deployed)? 
How do you build your project (Maven, ant ) ? Which version of Hibernate ? Hard to help you without some info.

EDIT : try to run `mvn dependency:tree` and post the result here, we should see what's wrong

EDIT : you have 2 versions of cglib. You should not manually include cglib as it is already included by hibernate as a transitive dependency.

Comment: Thanks for reply... i am using maven and dependency are <dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
<version>3.2.6.ga</version>
</dependency>   and cglib-nodep2.2.2 , asm4.1, asm-util4.1

Comment: thanks for reply. i have edited my Que detail with dependency tree result kindly check

Comment: which one should i remove.

Comment: The one you include in your POM. Hibernate includes cglib, with the version it needs.

Answer (score 0):

Just check how many cglib JARs you have in your project. Try to ensure that for your project + framework versions, you have the required cglib JAR and not some extra ones floating around.

Comment: Thanks for reply... i am using maven and dependency are <dependency> <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId> <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId> <version>3.2.6.ga</version> </dependency> and cglib-nodep2.2.2 , asm4.1, asm-util4.1

Answer (score 0):

You something missed on the class path. So that is why it showing "MappableContainerException" . This exception is related to the DB manager. So could you please stop your server,clean and redeploy it. Thanks.

Comment: @bhushan , what happens did you try this ?

Comment: i tried to update my dependency <dependency> <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId> <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId> <version>3.2.6.ga</version> </dependency> and cglib-nodep2.2.2 , asm4.1, asm-util4.1  but still not working ... i didnt understand DBmanager, may you elaborate it plz.

Comment: it may be root cause another thing, wait i check and let you know that.

Comment: i have posted dependency tree kindly check .

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by removing the glib dependency from pom as some other libraries have it internally, so if you see the dependencies or library jars, you will find more than one cglib jar.